# Is SEMIPRIME in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, primes

The title says it all: is there a deterministic polynomial time algorithm that tests for semiprimality? (A number $N$ is a [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) if it is the product of two primes.) I don't understand the ''PRIMES is in P'' paper, so I can't judge if it adapts, and I haven't had any luck searching this topic online.

If it is, is there a good (preferably concise) place to read about it?

Comment: I doubt that such an algorithm is known.

Answer (score 1):

I only know that before “Primes in P” was shown, there were excellent non-deterministic algorithms to show whether a number is prime or composite (if the algorithm says “it’s prime” for a composite number, it’s 1000 times more likely due to a hardware problem than due to a problem with the algorithm).

I know of no efficient non-deterministic algorithm to check if p is semi prime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know a reference for probabilistic semiprimality testing?

Comment: We have a nice theorem that says “every prime has an easily testable property X” that composites usually don’t have. It seems nobody found a similar theorem for semi primes so we are stuck. Nothing that works better than finding one factor f and checking that f and p/f are both prime.

Comment: By *non-deterministic* you probably mean *randomized*.